# Вывод файла в консоль частями

Tags: c++, итераторы

Необходимо считать файл и вывести его на экран частями, предположим по 1000 символов. Как добавить проверку на выход итератора за пределы файла?

```
ifstream in;
in.open("Fantastic1.txt", ios::in);
string str((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(in)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

string::iterator it = str.begin();
ostream_iterator<char> out(cout);
do
{

    if (_getch() != keyRight)
    {
        copy(it, it + 1000, out);
        it += 1000;
    }
} while (true);
```

Comment: О каком "выходе итератора за пределы файла" идет речь? Вы считали *весь* файл в строку и после этого с файлом уже не работаете. Откуда может взяться "выход за пределы файла"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, например, так:

```
string::iterator it = str.begin(), e = str.end();


auto n = std::distance(it,e);
n = (n < 1000) ? n : 1000;
copy(it, it + n, out);
it += n;
```